To do what it takes
I am interested in the idiom "do what it takes". Is it necessary for this idiom to include the goal? Can I say just "I will do what it takes.", when the goal is clear from context? Or does it need to be "I will do what it takes to win/help/..."?

You can abbreviate when the context is clear. "How are you going to fix the car? I'll do whatever it takes."

"I will do what it takes" = "I will do whatever it takes." They mean the same. Thing.

I will do what it takes [to do x] but it can stand alone in context.

The use of the phrase does not require a statement of the goal, as it is likely that the goal or objective has already been discussed.
A well-known use of the phrase is Mario Draghi’s:

He [Draghi] left those roles after his nomination by the European Council in 2011 to serve as President of the ECB. He presided over the institution during the Eurozone crisis, becoming famous throughout Europe for saying that he would be prepared to do "whatever it takes" to prevent the euro from failing. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Draghi

There’s a suggestion in the use of the phrase of a willingness to go beyond conventionally accepted standards or legal constraints to accomplish the purpose. Wiktionary defines it as “Anything, including measures which may be extreme or wrongful, that is required to achieve an objective.” https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatever_it_takes#:~:text=whatever%20it%20takes%20(uncountable),required%20to%20achieve%20an%20objective.
The recent (late June 2024) statement (https://kyivindependent.com/czech-pm-confirms/) of the Czech prime minister:

"The first shipment of ammunition from our initiative arrived in Ukraine some time ago. We are doing what it takes," Fiala said.

is fine. He is stating that what his government has done is meeting the need. He (or his translator) is correct not to use whatever in this case.

Thank you. The question appeared around a recent English language statement of the Czech prime minister. The critique claims that without a goal, the word "whatever" must be used. "I will do what it takes to help you." but "I will do whatever it takes".

I added a bit to the answer to cover this.

You can say "I will do what it takes", but the more common is "I will do whatever it takes".
Or another way to say "I will do my best".

whatever it takes doesn't mean the best I can do. What needs to be done is quantified by the task itself, not the speaker's ability to complete the task. All we know from I will do whatever it takes is that the speaker is confident he can complete the task, no matter what needs to be done.

"Whatever it takes, "  is an uncountable, idiomatic, sometimes euphemistic, expression,  for improper behavior; in short,  going the extra mile, so to speak, criminally, unethically to get something done or to reach an end.
A quick look at the definition on  The Free Dictionary website has it:
"Anything necessary to complete a task or goal, usually with a sense of reckless abandon." So, a negative connotation is attached to the idiomatic expression  "whatever it takes."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
